# How to pause when an assertion fails?

Tags: cypress

Cypress has assertions (`cy.should`) and a way to pause the test runner (`cy.pause`). Is there any way to connect the two, so that if a `should` fails, the test runner pauses?

I know I can do:

```
cy.should(whatever)
  .pause();
```

...but that pauses *every* time.  I only want to pause *if* the `should` fails.

You might think:

```
try {
  cy.should(whatever)
} catch (err) {
  cy.pause();
}
```

would work, but it doesn't, because (like everything in Cypress) the actual throwing of the error doesn't happen at the `should` line, it happens later on (when it can't be caught).

Similarly, I tried doing:

```
cy.on('uncaught:exception', () => {
  cy.pause();
});
cy.should(whatever);
```

But it doesn't work, presumably because by the time the error is caught using `cy.on`, it's already too late to pause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You answer fails with

> **CypressError:**
>
> `cy.should()` failed because you invoked a command inside the callback.
> ...
> Use `cy.then()` instead of `cy.should()`, or move any commands outside the callback function.

But if you just swap `.then()` for `should()` as the message suggests

```js
cy.visit('https://example.com')
cy.get('h1').then(el => {
  if (el.innerText !== 'foo') cy.pause();
  expect(el).to.have.text('foo');
})
```

it ***also fails*** because `expect()` is synchronous and `cy.pause()` is asynchronous - the `.then()` runs to completion before the newly queued pause command can run.

> **AssertionError:**
>
> expected `'<h1>'` to have text 'foo', but the text was 'Example Domain'

---

#### Use an else branch

```js
cy.visit('https://example.com')
cy.get('h1').then(el => {
  if (el.innerText !== 'foo') {
    cy.pause()
  } else {
    expect(el).to.have.text('foo')
  }
})
```

[image]

**But note**, with this pattern you lose retry.

Comment: Is there any way to get the same thing with the retry?  In other words, wait until the the operation has actually failed (vs. `then`, which triggers as soon as it potentially starts the failing process)?

Comment: I tried `.then( if (...) { cy.pause() }).should(...)` sequence, but the `.should()` runs before the `cy.pause()`.

Comment: I also tried using the `Cypress.queryFns.pause` synchronous version inside the orginal code you posted, but it didn't behave the same as `cy.pause()`.

Comment: Another option I didn't try is to add a custom pause that does a look-ahead to the `.should()`

Comment: This seems like such a basic bit of functionality: when something breaks, everyone wants to pause (or take a screenshot, or whatever).  I don't understand why Cypress doesn't have a simple built-in solution, given how good the library is otherwise :(

Comment: Actually, retry is probably not needed since the pause delays the assertion for however long it takes to click the resume button.

Comment: ***This seems like such a basic bit of functionality*** - you say that, but when do you want to pause? Something that's asynchronously loaded should only be paused at the end of the timeout period, because before then you are not looking at the final state. So you might as well add a hard `.wait()` for the whole timeout period, then inject the pause.

Comment: I just want to do it after a failure.  Taking screenshots, pausing, etc. before a failure has happened obviously isn't helpful.  If I am checking that an H1 says "Hi Mom!", I don't want the screenshot to be from when the page was loading and there was no H1: I want it to be when the page has an H1, which says "Hi Dad!".

Comment: So much of Cypress's timing seems to be about "try this function until it stops throwing errors, and then do the next thing".  But, there's a point where Cypress gives up and says "this function won't stop throwing errors, it's *actually* erroring now".  Wouldn't that point logically be the most useful debug point for pauses and screenshots?

Comment: The `cy.get('h1')` will retry until the `<h1>` is present, so not sure what you are asking there - which by the way,  `if (!el) return;` is never going to trigger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256064/discussion-between-machineghost-and-testerdick).

Comment: Also see [screenshotOnRunFailure](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Screenshots)

Comment: I think also, when the a `.should()` fails the test stops. If that's the only test, the DOM is still loaded and you can inspect the same as you would in a pause. So is a better question "How do I pause the run after a test fails"?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that you can use the callback form of `should` to solve this.  Instead of:

```
cy.get('h1').should('have.text', 'foo');
```

do the (more verbose):

```
cy.get('h1').should(el => {
  if (!el) return; // NOTE: el isn't always present
  if (el.innerText !== 'foo') cy.pause();

  expect(el).to.have.text('foo');
});
```